# HAL.dll Error on server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server that keeps restarting / crashing 2-3 times a day. Looking through the Event logs it seems that everything is running fine and then there is a restart. Pulling info from windows minidump it seems to be something with the Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL but I can't figure out anything more.

I have this log file from the minidump that might be helpful?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D4mWewTInKyxPkg199Z_YJdJsCh93TIH/view?usp=sharing

Does anyone have any ideas where I might dig further to figure out what is going on? I have run a chkdsk as well as memory and CPU tests and they all come back good.

Chris

Comment: I doubt there would be meaningful information in a mini dump file. Time to configure a full crash dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no harm in analyzing the crash dump to see if there's any useful information to help you track down the cause. I've analyzed mini dumps and found the problem by doing that.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: Thank you! This led me down to an issue with a driver.

Comment: Glad to help...